# Use criteria or query dsl to find all tables names in a given schema

Tags: postgresql, jpa, criteria-api

Is there a way to find all table names that begin with `t_` in a given schema name with criteria API or query DSL( or even database metadata)? If it exists, could you please show me how I can do it using a schema name or view? I'm using PostgreSQL for the database.
I don't want to use a native query.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use below query:

```
SELECT table_catalog,table_schema,table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name LIKE 't\_%'
AND table_type='BASE TABLE' -- to filter out Tables only, remove if you need to see views as well
```